# what are get and post on express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i couldn't understand that what post and get mean in expressjs. 
I am changing get and post on below code but nothing changing. Could someone explain ?

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();

    router.get('/add', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Homepage</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form method="POST" action="/added">
        <input name="product" type="text">
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
    `)
})

router.post('/added', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect('/add');
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Get is used to make get request. (where only way to pass data is in the url as a query string or params)
- typically used for fetching resources

2) Post is used to make post request. (where you can pass data(in body) too(with various format). so it doesnt appear in the url).
- typically used for creating resources

Comment: pleasure is all mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

They are the http request methods. If you write "get", then you can not catch a post request for example.